# Proving $\left(\int_{0}^{t}g(s)\text{ds}\right)^2=2\int_0^t\int_0^sg(r)g(s)\text{dr}\text{ds}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

I want to prove$$\left(\int_{0}^{t}g(s)\text{ds}\right)^2=2\int_0^t\int_0^sg(r)g(s)\text{dr}\text{ds}$$
with minimal assumptions on $g$ (except maybe that its measureable and that the integrals exist).
I can only prove it, if $g$ is continous. In this case, the function $f(s):=\int_0^sg(r)\text{dr}$ is in $C^1$ and we get
$$\frac{\text{d}}{ds}\left(f(s)^2\right)=2f(s)f'(s)$$
Integrating both sides and using $f(0)=0$ we get
$$f(t)^2=2\int_0^tf(s)f'(s)\text{ds}$$
yielding the claim if we plug in the definition of $f$.

I am hoping that someone knows how to prove the statement using Fubini or any other way that doesn't need the continuity assumption.

Comment: Hint: rewrite $2\int_{0}^{t}\int_{0}^{s} g(r)g(s) dr ds$ as sum of two identical integrals and use Fubini to show that one of them is equal to $\int_{0}^{t}\int_{r}^{t} g(r)g(s) ds dr$. Then the result will follow after you add the two integrals.

Answer (score 1):

It is enough to assume that $\mu:=g\cdot \lambda $ is a well-defined complex or signed measure that is finite in compact sets (where $\lambda $ stay for Lebesgue measure), then assuming that $t\geqslant 0$ and using Fubini's theorem you have that
$$
\int_{[0,t]} \left(\int_{[0,s]} \mu(dr)\right)\mu(ds)=
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\mathbf{1}_{[0,t]}(s)\mathbf{1}_{[0,s]}(r)\,\mu\otimes \mu(dr,ds)\\
=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}[0\leqslant r\leqslant s\leqslant t]\,\mu\otimes \mu(dr,ds)\tag1
$$

where the brackets inside the integral are Iverson's brackets and where $\mu\otimes \mu$ is the product measure. Now using Fubini's theorem and choosing a different order of integration for the iterated integrals than above you find that

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}[0\leqslant r\leqslant s\leqslant t]\,\mu\otimes \mu(dr,ds)=\int_{[0,t]}\left(\int_{[r,t]}\mu(ds)\right)\mu(dr)\tag2
$$

Now exchange the symbols of $s$ and $t$ in the last integral and add up to the first integral in (1), then you find that
$$
2 \int_{[0,t]} \left(\int_{[0,s]} \mu(dr)\right)\mu(ds)=\int_{[0,t]}\left(\int_{[0,t]}\mu(dr)+\mu(\{s\})\right)\mu(ds)\tag3
$$

As $\mu\ll \lambda $ then $\mu(\{s\})=0$ for all $s\in \mathbb{R}$, from where the equality that you want to prove follow from (3).∎